# HippoMocks - mocking methods with std::vector fail to compile

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, hippomocks

While trying out HippoMocks (Cygwin, GCC 4.5.3, CppUnit) to mock an interface, one of the methods is causing compilation to fail. Further triage shows that only mocking methods with std::vector as arguments would fail.

e.g.

```
m_Mocks.ExpectCall(m_EmpSvcMock.get(), IEmployeeServiceProxy::GetEmployees); // compile error!
m_Mocks.ExpectCall(m_EmpSvcMock.get(), IEmployeeServiceProxy::AddEmployee); // compile OK!
```

where

```
class IEmployeeServiceProxy
{
public:
    virtual ~IEmployeeServiceProxy() { }
    virtual void AddEmployee(const Employee&) = 0;
    virtual void GetEmployees(std::vector<Employee>&) = 0;
};

struct Employee
{
    boost::uuids::uuid Id;
    std::string Name;
};
```

Compiler error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stream_iterator.h: In member function ‘std::ostream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits>& std::ostream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = EmployeeServiceLib::Employee, _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::ostream_iterator<_Tp, _CharT, _Traits> = std::ostream_iterator<EmployeeServiceLib::Employee, char, std::char_traits<char> >]’:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/iterator:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/uuid/string_generator.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp:15,
                 from tests/../../RcfTestShared/IEmployeeService.hpp:7,
                 from tests/../IEmployeeServiceProxy.h:11,
                 from tests/ClientTest.h:13,
                 from tests/ClientTest.cpp:8:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:349:8:   instantiated from ‘static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = const EmployeeServiceLib::Employee*, _OI = std::ostream_iterator<EmployeeServiceLib::Employee, char, std::char_traits<char> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:404:70:   instantiated from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false, _II = const EmployeeServiceLib::Employee*, _OI = std::ostream_iterator<EmployeeServiceLib::Employee, char, std::char_traits<char> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:442:39:   instantiated from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false, _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const EmployeeServiceLib::Employee*, std::vector<EmployeeServiceLib::Employee> >, _OI = std::ostream_iterator<EmployeeServiceLib::Employee, char, std::char_traits<char> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:474:18:   instantiated from ‘_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const EmployeeServiceLib::Employee*, std::vector<EmployeeServiceLib::Employee> >, _OI = std::ostream_iterator<EmployeeServiceLib::Employee, char, std::char_traits<char> >]’
../../RCF/RCF-1.3.1/include/RCF/Tools.hpp:116:9:   instantiated from ‘std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::vector<_RealType>&) [with T = EmployeeServiceLib::Employee, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
../../hippomocks/HippoMocks/hippomocks.h:94:5:   instantiated from ‘static void printArg<T>::print(std::ostream&, T, bool) [with T = std::vector<EmployeeServiceLib::Employee>&, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
../../hippomocks/HippoMocks/hippomocks.h:170:5:   instantiated from ‘void ref_tuple<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P>::printTo(std::ostream&) const [with A = std::vector<EmployeeServiceLib::Employee>&, B = NullType, C = NullType, D = NullType, E = NullType, F = NullType, G = NullType, H = NullType, I = NullType, J = NullType, K = NullType, L = NullType, M = NullType, N = NullType, O = NullType, P = NullType, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
tests/ClientTest.cpp:47:1:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stream_iterator.h:196:2: error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream_iterator<EmployeeServiceLib::Employee, char, std::char_traits<char> >::ostream_type’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/ostream:579:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Tp = EmployeeServiceLib::Employee]’
```

Comment: Well you've deleted the error messages now, but in the brief time I saw them I thought the problem was that it was trying to compare Employee objects with operator==. Do you have operator== defined for class Employee? operator== for std::vector<T> will work as long as operator== is defined for T.

Comment: @jahhaj: I've updated HippoMocks to the latest version from their svn and I now have a different error...

Comment: And the different error is? Also you didn't answer my question, do you have operator== defined for Employee? I would think that is quite important for any unit testing of an Employee class.

Comment: You should define operator==, POD has nothing to do with it. operator== does not get defined automatically even for POD types.

Comment: @jahhaj: Adding the operator doesn't help. Still the same error.

Comment: Possibly it's complaining that you don't have operator<< defined for Employee, but I'm not certain. I think you've missed the last line of your error messages? In any case I would read the documentation and see what requirements they have for the class being tested. Requiring you to define operator== and operator<< and maybe others is pretty standard for a unit testing framework.

Comment: @jahhaj: You are right. The documentation did mention overloading operator== and operator<< but it mentioned it's only required if "change the way you compare types" and "change the way you print types". And not to mention it's under "Advanced stuff".

Comment: @jahhaj: write an answer the comments you wrote and I'll make it as correct.

Comment: It should've converted it to a NotPrintable implicitly and then used its printing logic - in the source around line 350. That explains why it only fails with a vector - the vector itself has an operator<< but the class that it's trying to print doesn't, so it's not HippoMocks failing but rather the vector's operator<< not being well defined (due to you not having an operator<<). I'll add this to the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @dascandy: It looks like the svn trunk version doesn't need operator== in Employee for std::vector too. Could the same be done for operator<<?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly it's complaining that you don't have operator<< defined for Employee, but I'm not certain. I think you've missed the last line of your error messages? In any case I would read the documentation and see what requirements they have for the class being tested.

Requiring you to define operator== and operator<< and maybe others is pretty standard for a unit testing framework. If you think about it a unit testing framework is going to need to compare objects of the types you are testing and maybe going to try and output those objects when things go wrong.

Comment: There's a fix in there to automatically use something else if the class doesn't have an operator<< defined. It'll print "???" instead. There's no default compare anymore as no possible solution would make sense.

Comment: @dascandy: I have several questions to follow -- how do I contact you directly rather than asking questions on SO?

Comment: You can always use my email address dascandy@gmail.com. I just noticed the wiki has gone corrupt - oops... I'll fix that first, it should've had most of the answers but right now it only has a database error.